# Subset columns in dataframe X based on columns of dataframe Y

Tags: r, subset

I would like to subset my `X` data frame based in name collumns of `Y` dataframe:

My `X`dataframe:

```
NE001   NE002   NE003
  1       2       3
```

My `Y`dataframe:

```
 NE001  NE003
  10      5
```

My expected output:

```
NE001   NE003
  1       3
```

Any ideas? Thank you! ps. I would like to subset from collumn name, not from collumn number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will do it:

```
X[,names(X) %in% names(Y)]
```

Perhaps you want to take a closer look at some R introduction text, see e.g. [these R links](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info).